# Core Graphics Transparent Overlay

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-graphics

I'm replacing the background view of a `UITableViewCell` with my own custom subclass of `UIView`, in which I override the `drawRect` method with my own, which creates a multi-colored and changing background.

The problem is that when the `TableViewCell` is selected, the graphics under are completely hidden and it looks odd. I need to create a custom `selectedBackgroundView` in order to fix this. The problem is that that view needs to create a blue gradient tint over the graphics already there, and I don't know how to draw a `CGRect` or something similar that is partially transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Write this In your - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
// To draw semi transparent Square
// Create Current Context To Draw
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIBezierPath *square = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
// following method will fill red color with alpha 0.4 last one in parameter list
// first 3 are Red, Green and Blue Respectively.
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0, 0, 0.4);
[square fill];
[square stroke];
```